# Find occurence in arrayList

Tags: groovy, arraylist, char

I have an arrayList of values `def list = ['a', 'e', 'u', 'o', 'A', 'E', 'O', 'U'];`

How can I find if an certain char is included in that list? I've tried `contains` but it didn't work. Always returned `false`.

```
def char = 'a'
println(list.contains(char));
```

Comment: This is plain Java basics. Why is there still a problem after the answer? If you still think `contains` (which works perfectly) is verbose then you can use `in` like `'a' in list`.

Answer (score 1):

`char` is a keyword in Groovy (and Java), also, that list contains Strings.

Try this:

```
def list = ['a', 'e', 'u', 'o', 'A', 'E', 'O', 'U']
def s = 'a'
println list.contains( s )
```

Comment: Yeah, apart from I changed `def char = 'a'` to `def s = 'a'` and `list.contains(char)` to `list.contains( s )`.  Can you post the actual code you've tried? The code you posted as an example won't compile because of the errors...

Comment: @Jacob this code works, btw. So, if you have same code - it should work too